# how to remove this error in Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*;

public class DataInsertDemo1{

    public static void main(String kl[]) throws SQLException,Exception{
        String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"System","System1996");

        Scanner sc=new Scanner("System.in");
        System.out.println("enter person name");
        String name=sc.next();

        System.out.println("Enter DOP(dd-mm-yyyy):");
        String dop=sc.next();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy"); 
        java.util.Date udate=sdf.parse(dop);
        long l=udate.getTime();
        java.sql.Date sdate=new java.sql.Date(l);

        String sql="insert into userdate values(?,?)";

        PreparedStatement  ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setDate(2,sdate);

        int rc=ps.executeUpdate();

            if(rc == 0){
                System.out.println("Record not inserted");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("record is inserted");
            }

    con.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new Scanner("System.in");
```

to

```
new Scanner(System.in);
```

You should also change

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

to

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner("System.in");
```

You don't need to pass the String to the constructor in this case, because `"System.in"` is not the path.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
```

will work.
Also, it's a good practice to check if scanner has next token

```
if (sc.hasNext()) {
    sc.next() 
}
```